# Javascript - Storing high scores for my game in a JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I working on a game built using Javascript and HTML5 canvas. Almost everything is done except that I'm not able to deploy some kind of functionality that'll allow me to store high scores.

Since the game is just an HTML page that includes a lot of Javascript files i.e. no database, my plan of action was to store all the high scores in a hash table like -

```
{
  "Bruce":100,
  "Alexis":84,
  "Megan":69,
  "Carlos":52
}
```

and then store that as a JSON file. Each time a user loads up the game, the JSON file will be parsed and the high scores could be displayed by iterating over the hash table.

But I can't get this to work. Here are the problems I'm running into -

1. jQuery's getJSON method won't allow me to get a file that is stored locally. So I'm storing the file on my Github and passing the URL as an argument. Is that the right fix? I'm ultimately planning to host this game using Github pages so I thought I'll have to change the URL a little bit when I deploy to production.
2. After that, it threw this error at me...

   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

   I looked around and installing a Allow-Control-Allow-Origin extension on Chrome fixed it. Again, is that the right fix?
3. And that brings us to where I'm right now. This is how my method call looks like -

this

```
$.getJSON('https://github.com/.../scores.json', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
}).fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
  var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
  console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
});
```

I'm getting this error on the last line -

Request Failed: parsererror, SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Also, please lemme know if I'm following the right approach to the problem that I'm trying to solve...

Comment: 1. You'll have to use `raw.github.com/...` (just click the "raw" button when viewing the JSON file on GH), 2. it is a really bad idea for a JS-only game to even have a high score table, because nothing prevents random people from hacking it and, depending on how you implement the write operation,  allowing them to write arbitrary data into that file or repository, or even take over your GitHub account entirely.

Comment: Oops! I definitely don't want people to mess up my Github. Whats the better way to achieve the high scores table then? I mean I need to store the data somewhere right?

Comment: you'll probably have to store it serverside somewhere. either on your own server or a server service.

Comment: Any old server-side language will do... but the scores themselves will still be hackable, because the server can't verify them. I can see myself having a score of `2147483647` already :P

Comment: Aight guys I got it to work! Thx a lot! None of y'all will ever dare to hack my game's high scores lol jk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the request returns the actual github page instead of the raw file.

You can address your requests to **raw.githubusercontent.com** instead to get the raw file.